# How to stop at first match in C++ regular expression?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, flex-lexer

I'm trying to remove comments in C++ with flex.

This is my example code:

```
cout << "Pulapka \" \
       // ma \
       /* ma */ \
       " << endl;
cout << /*Proba*/"Zabawa \" // ala i kot " << endl;
```

I want match everything between " ".

My regural expression:

```
(\"[^[]*]*")
```

I want to stop my matching after second quotation marks. That's mean I need only this fragment:

```
"Pulapka \" \
      // ma \
      /* ma */ \
      "
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Use non-greedy matching

Comment: @sshashank124
I know that I should use non-greedy matching, but I have no idea how. Can you please show me how ?

Answer (score 2):

The following regex works for me:

`(\".*?(?<!\\)("))`

You can then extract the first group which is exactly what you want.

Note: I don't know how it works for C++ but I had to use the `s` flag

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/xL4kU8